# Trouble setting up wifi, daemon failed to start

Tags: wireless

I am trying to set up wireless on my Raspberry Pi 3 using Jessie version (no GUI)

I have tried setting up wifi by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and using the `wpa_passphrase` command as follows

```
wpa_passphrase MySSID password | sudo tee -a /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

but whenever I try to bring up the device wlan0 with `sudo ifup --force wlan0` I get the following error:

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlan0.
```

When I check the syslog I see the following.

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

It even comes up when I try to set power management off on the raspberry pi

I am assuming the nl80211 driver is missing, but I cannot find any explanation on how to fix this issue. How do I install the driver?

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that you're using the wrong driver, not that it's missing. Try running,

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0
```

This will use the wext driver instead of the nl80211 driver. You can read more by using the "man wpa_supplicant" command. If the command succeeds it should output something like:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[blablabla]: invalid argument
ioctl[blablabla]: invalid argument
```

If you get a message like that ^
You should be able to connect to your wifi by running

```
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

I got most of this information from:
http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-connect-to-wpawpa2-wifi-network.html

Check out that source if you run into additional problems. If the guide doesn't help, let us know what went wrong.

Note: I still can't get my rPi3 to connect to wifi on boot, but I'll edit this when I do.

I hope this helps.